# How to package Protractor page objects in Angular 8 library

Tags: angular, protractor

I have an Angular 8 library with a number of UI components. With each component I have a page object class.

How would I go about packaging the page object classes so that an app which uses my component library can use the page objects in their Protractor tests? Do I need to customize ng-packgr somehow?

Comment: Could you add some more details about what you are trying to do? Not sure I fully understand your question. Your app components and page objects should be completely independent of each other. You don't want to "package" them up together.

Comment: I'm in the process of creating a component library of Angular 8 components.  For example date picker, calendar, etc.  I want to create page objects for those components so the developers who use the library don't need to.   I would like to package the page objects in the npm package.  This way when they install the component library they also get the associated page objects.

Comment: @ScottWalter - did you ever find a way of doing this? I am facing the same requirement with an Angular 9 library of components I am working on and would also like to export corresponding protractor page objects.